# How to make the CHECK button to the right of the zipcode textfield using CSS code.

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

**How to make the zipcode field & CHECK button on oneline using CSS. My website page is responsive**. I am providing you the css file of this section. I had tried but output is not coming which i want. I want the CHECK button to the right side of the textfield. I am attaching the screehshot. Any help will be appreciated. I had added the HTML & CSS code below for any queries.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .z-btn button {
    background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    position: unset;
  }
  .z-btn input.product-custom-option {
    border: 0 none;
    float: right !important;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 31px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    width: 80%;
  }
}
div.product-view .add-to-cart {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
div.product-view .add-to-cart-buttons {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 82%;
}
.z-btn label {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("img/van-icon.png") no-repeat scroll right 2px top 3px / 96% auto;
  float: left;
  font-size: 13px;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 28px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 37px;
}
. .z-btn button {
  background: #000 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: right !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  /*margin-top: -31px;*/
  position: absolute;
}
.input-box > div#cod_msg {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.cod-suc,
.cod-error {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-color: -moz-use-text-color #ccc #ccc;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: none solid solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 2px 11px 3px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: -3px;
  width: 100%;
}
#cod_msg img {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  width: 3%;
}
.cod-error {
  color: #ff0000;
}
.cod-suc {
  color: #009036;
}
div.product-view .add-to-cart-buttons button#zip-check.button {
  line-height: 32px;
  min-height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input placeholder="Enter your pincode" value="" name="cod" class="product-custom-option required-entry" id="cod" size="29" style="color:black; font-size:12px" type="text">

<button id="zip-check" class="button" type="button" onclick="checkCOD();" name="zip-check" title="Check">
```

[image]

Comment: can u post the html code too?

Comment: I had added the html code as u requested

Comment: Can we see the html for the whole section that contains buttons and input fields? From the screenshot we can tell that the little truck icon, input field and the check button are wider than "Add to Cart" above. You need to size those to fit and display properly.

Comment: Any answer stackys

Comment: First of all, your div.z-btn is not responsive all elements which in has a fixed size.

To be sure that children of .z-btn stay in one line, use width with percentage on each child.

Comment: how to do this to make responsive & to make on oneline

Answer (score 0):

## Bootstrap button on the right

Using the code posted in the answer:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type="text" placeholder="enter your zip code"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
```